# Am I adding a bunch of unnecessary event handlers?

Tags: jquery, events, bind

I suspect that I may be using event handlers wrong here. Can someone please point me to a correct/better way of doing this?

Basically I am monitoring the window.resize event. If the window is smaller than an on screen element I bind to the scroll event. My problem is that the resize event gets thrown continuously. I think this means that I am continuously rebinding to the scroll event. That seems bad. Thoughts on a better way to do this?

I could use a variable to keep track of whether or not it is already bound... but that seems clunky to me.

```
    //when window is resized check whether the sidebar still fits on screen
    $(window).resize(checkIt);

    function checkIt() {    
        botOfSidebar = $(obj).height() + topOfSidebar;
        if (botOfSidebar < $(window).height()) {    
            //discard event handler
            $(window).unbind("scroll", dynamicallyAdjustIt);  
            fixIt();                                                                                            //fix it in place
        }
        else {
            console.log("dynamically adjust it");
            $(window).scroll(dynamicallyAdjustIt);      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply bind the scroll event once, and then when the size is below a threshold, update a variable to enable it?

AKA

```
$(window).resize(function() { });
$(window).scroll(function()
{
     if( /* Check to see if window is greater than some set size */ )
         return;

     // Do Logic
});
```

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting to this today. It seemed wasteful to me to do a check on every scroll event when I know that I only need to do it when the window resizes. This will be in place on my company's website so I would prefer to have it ship-shape on the first go.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
$( window ).bind( 'scroll', function () {

    if ( $( obj ).height() + topOfSideBar < $( window ).height() ) {
        fixIt();
    } else {
        dynamicallyAdjustIt();
    }

});
```

Comment: See my comment to Tejs. I would prefer not to run checks on every scroll event if I don't need to. I am looking for a more elegant solution.